# Create a new project on Github/ Gitlab via Terminal

Tags: git, bash, github-api, gitlab-api

I want to add a new project on Gitlab only using the command line (bash). Is there a way or do I have to go to the Gitlab page and add the project via GUI?

I explicitely don't mean to add a local repository to a remote - I know how to do this. I merely look for a way to do the project creation step as well from the terminal without heading over to the Gitlab page.

Comment: You might want to check out the API of github or gitlab. Maybe [this](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/create-a-new-project-in-a-group-using-api/1552) is even the answer you're looking for, but I didn't look at that too closely

Comment: Yep, seems to be doable with github too: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create

Comment: Thank you guys, all valuable leads...I need to dig into it. But the idea using the API seems the road to go...

Comment: I believe that solves it: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/create-a-new-project-in-a-group-using-api/1552. ; thank you lucidbrot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer no, because you are using Git SCM, which is not specially designed for GitHub, Gitlab, Bitbucket or even local repo. Git SCM is designed to integrate with every Git version control repository.

But you can write a custom command on Git SCM or shell script to integrate with GitLab or GitHub API to create new repo easily.

Open `.gitconfig` file and then add following command:

```
[alias]
create-repo = !sh -c "curl -i -H 'Authorization: token YOUR_GITHUB_TOKEN' -X POST ....
```

And then run `git create-repo name`

- [Gitlab API - create project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project)
- [GitHub API - create repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/)
- [Git SCM - Aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)

Comment: What do you mean by “or even local repo”?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It means creating a bare repository on the local machine, take a look at [here](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) for more information.

Comment: That wasn’t my question. I wondered why you said git scm wasn’t made for “even local repo”.

Comment: Mehdi, thank you for the quick reply, any chance that you could provide the command to do an alias? I lack the knowledge....I‘ll get the token;-) would be great. Merci

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because git scm is not designed to be more than an scm, It could create repositories but it doesn't have the ability to list, search... them and technically it's blind at realizing other repositories at the same time.

Comment: @aerioeus yw, I added git alias info

Comment: Great, thanks a lot Mehdi!